# Vertical Align Middle an image in an a tag in a div

Tags: css, image, alignment, vertical-alignment

This has probably been done before but I can't find a solution for my specific case. I have the following:

```
<div class="holder" style="height:260px;width:260px;">
<a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

How can I get the image to align into the middle of the div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, img is an inline-element, which means, that it's being aligned to the baseline of the text of your parent-element. This leaves a nasty space underneath your image.

You can prevent this with

```
img{
   display:[inline-]block; /* or inline-block if the img isn't the only element in your div*/
}
```

This removes the reserved space underneath the image.

you can change the alignment by

```
img{
   vertical-align: [top|middle|bottom|baseline|...] ;
}
```

to align it according to your text.

In general, you can only vertical-align inline elements. So an image with `display:block` won't be affected by a vertical alignment declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle; 
display: table-cell;
```

to the div's style.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
.img
{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your mark up then you can use `line-height` property for this. Like this:

```
.holder{
    line-height:260px;
}
```